# Keyup Event not working in CKEDITOR while key event works

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am using CKEDITOR 3.x and its works successfully. Now I want CKEDITOR value on `keyup` function .When I use `key` function I got data but when I use `keyup` function is doesn't works.
Here is my code

```
CKEDITOR.replace(ckViewEn,{
    language:'en-gb'
}).on('key', function(e) {
    alert(123); // works
});

CKEDITOR.replace(ckViewEn,{
        language:'en-gb'
    }).on('keyup', function(e) {
        alert(123); // Not working
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Editor doesn't have a keyup(all) event(s). If you want to catch it you need bind it to editors document object model. & if not working then you need to use with setTimeout().

```
editor.on('contentDom', function( event ) {
  editor.document.on('key', function(event) {
    console.log('my key');
  });
  editor.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
    console.log('my keyup');
  });
  editor.document.on('keydown', function(event) {
    console.log('my keydown');
  });
  editor.on('key', function(event) {
    console.log('raw key');
  });
  editor.on('keyup', function(event) {
    console.log('raw keyup');
  });
  editor.on('keydown', function(event) {
    console.log('raw keydown');
  });
  editor.document.on('mouseup', function(event) {
    console.log('mouseup');
  });
});
```

For more information source :-

[CKEditor Key-Event](https://ckeditor.com/old//forums/CKEditor/Key-Event)

[CKEditor Get key event type](https://ckeditor.com/old//forums/CKEditor-3.x/Get-key-event-type)

Comment: CKEDITOR.replace(ckViewEn,{
  language:'en-gb'
 }).on('contentDom', function(event) {
     var text = event.editor.getData();
     console.log(text);
     CKEDITOR.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
      console.log('my keyup');
    });
 }); Still Now its not working. please see my code

Comment: did not get what you want to say?

Comment: `CKEDITOR.replace(ckViewEn,{ language:'en-gb' }).on('contentDom', function(event) { var text = event.editor.getData(); console.log(text); CKEDITOR.document.on('keyup', function(event) { console.log('my keyup'); }); });` This is my code but still now its not working.

Comment: CKEDITOR.on('keyup', function() {
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('my keyup');
}, 1000);
}

Comment: HI, I have use your code but nothing is changing still now nothing in the console.

Comment: now you have one option to handle this you need to handle after rendering CKEditor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162145/discussion-between-raj-and-parth-raval).